# asp.net radiobutton is rendered with multiple value attributes

Tags: asp.net, gridview, attributes, radio-button

I have a gridview having item template as below

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoSel" runat="server"  />     
</ItemTemplate>
```

it's getting rendered as

```
    <input id="rdoSel" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$tabFund$TabPanel3$gvAutoMatchFund$ctl06$rdoSel" value="rdoSel" />
```

In gridview rowdatabound event when I set this value to some new value,

```
    protected void gvAutoMatchFund_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            USP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult = (USP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult)e.Row.DataItem;


            string sValue = "rdoSel_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.DYNAMO_FUNDID
                        + "_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.INVESTRAN_SYSTEMFUNDID
                        + "_" + objUSP_MDM_SUGGESTED_AUTOMATCH_FUNDResult.INVESTRAN_FUNDID;

            RadioButton rdoSel = (RadioButton)e.Row.FindControl("rdoSel");         
            rdoSel.InputAttributes["value"] = sValue; 
        }
    }
```

it gets rendered as below having 'value' attribute twice.

```
    <input id="rdoSel" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$tabFund$TabPanel3$gvAutoMatchFund$ctl06$rdoSel" value="rdoSel" value="rdoSel_DD62E413-603B-4514-8798-FE9F0C478A35_418_1498" />
```

Any clue why it is happening and how to solve it? could not get answer thru many other forums so posting here.

Comment: why are you doing this?